# Crosswalk 14 - orientation is not changing

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

In my app build on crosswalk 14 and ionic there is no orientation change. if You rotate device - no change.
My `congif.xml file`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="pl.polskieszlaki.PolskieSzlaki" android-versionCode="6" version="2.0.1"  android-installLocation="preferExternal" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Polskie Szlaki</name>
    <description>Flagowa aplikacja portalu PolskieSzlaki.pl. Znajdziesz tutaj opisy tysięcy atrakcji z całej Polski
    </description>
    <author email="biuro@polskieszlaki.pl" href="http://www.polskieszlaki.pl">Łukasz Piernikarczyk</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

And `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="2.0.1" package="pl.polskieszlaki.PolskieSzlaki" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBINjjNZBV2_yrk_L6vJfmLYshvzdXMBO4" />
        <activity android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Without crosswalk everything works great.

My codrova plugins:

```
com.bunkerpalace.cordova.YoutubeVideoPlayer 1.0.1 "CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer"
com.google.playservices 19.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.7.2 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 4.3.19-dev "SocialSharing"
nl.x-services.plugins.toast 2.1.1 "Toast"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.4 "Globalization"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
org.pushandplay.cordova.apprate 1.1.7 "AppRate"
plugin.google.maps 1.2.5 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
plugin.http.request 1.0.4 "phonegap-http-request"
```